# How to detect if your site is loaded on SFSafariViewController

Tags: javascript, safari, sfsafariviewcontroller

How can you tell using javascript if your site is being loaded in an SFSafariViewController, and not pure Safari? I looked at window.navigator.userAgent, but it outputs the same thing on both browsers.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Apple Developer thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12986) they should be different; I'd also check [iOS User Agents](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/operating_system_name/ios/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `window.MicrodataExtractor` is available (not undefined) in full iOS Safari. So either it is an in-app browser or SFSafariViewController. I use `inapp-spy` for in-app detection. I'm not using `window.MicrodataExtractor` detection on anything production-level yet, but from recent tests works on my iPhone and iPad Safari. There might be other hints - if I find them I’ll share.